# Crawl a full domain and load all h1 into a item

Tags: python, scrapy

I am relatively new to python and scrapy. What I want to achieve is to crawl a number of websites mainly company websites. Crawl the full domain and extract all the h1 h2 h3. Create a record that contains the domain name and a string with all the h1 h2 h3 from that domain. Basically have a Domain item and a large string containing all the headers.

I would like the output to be 
DOMAIN, STRING(h1,h2,h2) - from all the urls on this domain

The problem I have is that each URL goes into separate Items. I know I haven't gotten very far but a hint in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Basically, how I create an outer loop so that the yield statement keeps going until the next domain is up.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.http import Request
from Autotask_Prospecting.items import AutotaskProspectingItem
from Autotask_Prospecting.items import WebsiteItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from nltk import clean_html


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Webcrawler'
    allowed_domains = [ l.strip() for l in open('Domains.txt').readlines() ]
    start_urls = [ l.strip() for l in open('start_urls.txt').readlines() ]


    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item'),  
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        xpath = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        loader = XPathItemLoader(item=WebsiteItem(), response=response)
        loader.add_xpath('h1',("//h1/text()"))
        loader.add_xpath('h2',("//h2/text()"))
        loader.add_xpath('h3',("//h3/text()"))
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1):

> yield statement keeps going until the next domain is up.

cannot be done, things are done in parallel and there is no way to make domain crawling serially.

what you **can** do is to [write a pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) that will accumulate them and yield the entire structure on `spider_close`, something like:

```
# this assume your item looks like the following
class MyItem():
    domain = Field()
    hs = Field()


import collections
class DomainPipeline(object):

    accumulator = collections.defaultdict(set)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        accumulator[item['domain']].update(item['hs'])

    def close_spider(spider):
        for domain,hs in accumulator.items():
            yield MyItem(domain=domain, hs=hs)
```

usage:

```
>>> from scrapy.item import Item, Field
>>> class MyItem(Item):
...     domain = Field()
...     hs = Field()
... 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> accumulator = defaultdict(set)
>>> items = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...     items.append(MyItem(domain='google.com', hs=[str(i)]))
... 
>>> items
[{'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['0']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['1']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['2']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['3']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['4']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['5']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['6']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['7']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['8']}, {'domain': 'google.com', 'hs': ['9']}]
>>> for item in items:
...     accumulator[item['domain']].update(item['hs'])
... 
>>> accumulator
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'google.com': set(['1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8'])})
>>> for domain, hs in accumulator.items():
...     print MyItem(domain=domain, hs=hs)
... 
{'domain': 'google.com',
 'hs': set(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])}
>>>
```

Comment: How does this accumulator work? I tried to implement your code and I only get collections is not defined.

Comment: I created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353438/scrapy-pipeline-unhashable-type-list. I tried your new code and get the error of use item['domain']. I used this syntax in the new question.

Comment: The main issue is that the item values cannot be fed into the defaultdict. Since they appear to be be similar to a list object. I need a way to convert these objects so they can be read by the defaultdict.

Comment: It works for in the usage example. However in the spider class I need to add global variable to accumulator, and close_Spider(spider,set).To actually get it to run. But it does not manage to scrape anything just None. This was harder than I initially thought...

Comment: sorry to hear, you should not define global parameter nor change close_spider signature... keep practising till you get it right

Comment: Sure will, thanks for the help though :). If I do not define it as global I need to do self.accumulator[item['domain']].update(item['hs']) for it to work within the function.